# Can I add an elapsed time bar for Rhythmbox player in the sound menu?

Tags: sound, rhythmbox

If so, how do I get to be this way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looked promising, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with the newest version of Rhythmbox though. Take a look, and maybe there is a way to convert it to work.

https://code.google.com/p/rb-fast-position-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I think this [Media Player Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/55/media-player-indicator/) Extension is, what you was searching for.